# Get the dimensions of a H.264 MP4

Tags: php, video, mp4, h.264

Does anybody know a ready-made, reliable way to tell the dimensions (width x height) of a MP4 encoded using the H.264 codec without ffmpeg or similar extensions, in pure PHP?

> Thanks for all the answers folks. The bounty is running out and I will not have time to check the offered solutions before it does. I will accept the solution that I feel has the greatest likelihood to work.

Comment: Nothing ready-made that I know of, but the MPEG-4 standard is extremely well documented. You could parse the data out of the file yourself with a few hours coding.

Comment: If you have the proper permissions on your server, you could execute the `ffmpeg` executable with the right command line arguments to get back a width x height I'm sure

Comment: Nope, no command line access on this server. That's why I'm asking for PHP. But certainly the first choice when you have the permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like http://code.google.com/p/php-mp4info/ might be your answer. It reads MP4's but it doesn't mention anything about H.264.

also, what OS are you using?

Comment: Wow, this looks good! Chances are that the dimensions are stored in the metadata no matter what encoding is used. I will take a look into that. The site will be running on Linux.

Comment: the only place I see this falling short is if a video doesn't have the metadata properly emebeded.

Comment: Good luck. If you get it figured out would you mine posting it here?

Comment: @AlecGorge This library does not read `.mp4` files. only `.f4v`

Comment: Old, issue but I came upon this. Android video's in portrait modus for some reason mix the width and height, I do get this from mp4's so that works

Answer (score 4):

[getID3](http://www.getid3.org) is pure php and extracts an amazing amount of information from media files of all sorts. It will depend on what encoded your file in the first place as to what metadata is available and how reliable it is. getID3 has a nice demo page with lots of different file types. I tried to post more links but as a newbie I only get one.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but as far as I can see, getID3 doesn't do MP4.

Comment: On the demo page (http://www.getid3.org/demo/) there are two .mp4 files e.g. http://www.getid3.org/demo/MP4%20-%20aac.mp4.html. As I mentioned it will depend on what was used to encode your mp4, if it was Quicktime I bet getID3 would work. Without more information or an example file it is difficult to tell. What encoded your file?

Answer (score 1):

What comes to mind:

- [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) a huge project with GUI, but also has a CLI
- mp4info (part of the seemingly defunct [mp4mpeg](http://mpeg4ip.sourceforge.net/) project) is almost perfect for this
- [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) although this is overkill for the task.  then again, you very well may need it for other tasks

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg and php: http://www.lampdeveloper.co.uk/linux/detecting-a-videos-dimensions-using-php-and-ffmpeg.html

Comment: the question mentions "without ffmpeg" :)

Answer (score 1):

[php-reader](https://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ISO14496) is a full implementation of the `ISO 14496` done in pure PHP. You can use this library to read all of the boxes which the mp4 consist of, like the moov atom containing metadata about the file.

Answer (score 0):

Native PHP does not support anything like this, ffmpeg is only one library that come on my mind.